# How to handle cookies securely during the REST API call in SWIFT 3 or 4?

Tags: ios, swift, api, security, cookies

How can we securely handle the cookies during the API calls? I want the cookies only accessible by the app, not other apps installed on my device. Or can we block to store the cookie's data on my apps? Please suggest or guide me. Thanks in advance

Comment: How we securely use the Improper session handling with Improper flags in Cookies Headers in API calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right that "Cookies are not shared among applications in iOS.". We also configured the session using ephemeralSessionConfiguration and NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyNever before calling the API.

For your reference : 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1410529-ephemeralsessionconfiguration?language=objc
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nshttpcookieacceptpolicy/nshttpcookieacceptpolicynever?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/httpcookiestorage) for `HTTPCookieStorage` ...

"Cookies are not shared among applications in iOS."